# Is the Weyl Postulate correct?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, geodesics

The [Weyl postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_postulate) in cosmology states that worldlines do not intersect but it can be shown in GR that using [Raychaudhuri equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) that geodesics can intersect if there is curvature so I'm really confused.

Comment: They geodesics would intersect if they could be extended indefinitely. If the space-time is singular, in the sense that there are incomplete geodesics, they will not intersect.